# Proper way to build web app with Django on remote web server

Tags: python, django, ssh, centos

I'm fairly new to Django so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm starting my first build of a web app on my remote web server. I am currently SSH'ing to the server and have started the Django project. I just launched the development server for the Django project, and it automatically serves at http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

My question is- what is the proper way to build a Django web app remotely on a server? Am I supposed to build the app on my computer and then transfer the project to my web server after it is complete? Or is there a way for me to access the development server without messing with the domains/ip addresses of the websites that are live on my web server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a Django specific question as the same basic methodology goes for any software development project.

- Create different settings files for development and production. For Django this will involve setting the ALLOWED_HOSTS in your production settings as you mentioned as well as other settings. [This checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/) is helpful for this step. Use environment variables to hide secrets and set them in your development and production machines as appropriate.
- Use a version control system such as git and push changes locally and then pull them onto your production server then run your Django server.

  - Do one better and setup a CI/CD pipeline to automate this

Comment: Maybe this is for a separate question- but what about databases? I have a database on my webserver already set up. Do I need to create a database on my local PC and then merge when I deploy or how does that work?

Comment: Usually you have separate databases for development and production so I'd recommend creating one of your local PC for development. If you are generating data in development and want it in your production environment, maybe there is a way to seed your production environment by writing a migration script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're supposed to build working project on your computer :)
You probably cant efficiently write something good on the remote server.

Then you will probably create the git repository, for example on gitlab.
Then you will work on your computer building your project.
When you want to see it on the remote server, you will pull your project there.

It will be a little tricky for a first time to correctly deploy it, but it's not really that bad + there are a lot of good instructions out there, for ex:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

I hope I correctly understood your question.